# change drop down list values when checkbox is checked in jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

this is my code to change the drop down list values when the checkbox is checked. I use asp.net mvc framework and java script to call the action. The list of the drop-down should show only the expired medicines when the checkbox is checked. But, it results in (Error: [object:object]). It didn't hit the controller action 'getmedicine'. Can anyone help me?

```
function GetMedicineList(_isExp) {

    var url = "getmedicine";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { IsExp: _isExp },
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>Please Select Expired Medicine</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }
            $("#clientId").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });

}
```

and in the view,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsExp, new { Id = "isExp",  @onchange = "GetMedicineList(this.value);" })
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#clientId").append(markup)` ?

Comment: If it didn't hit the controller action, you probably call wrong url. In your example you basically call http://www.yourdomain.com/getmedicine. Is it correct?

Comment: I tried that, but nothing happened.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers development console and see why the Http request failed.

Comment: @Tacud     var url = "/UserMedicalHistory/getmedicine".  I tried this. But the same error repeated.

Comment: can you show action?

Comment: @Usman. I think there is no error in action. it works properly when the check box is not checked. The problem is with the checkbox js. It did'nt hit the action method.

Comment: still it would be better to show action for further assistance

Comment: you could use `url = 'URL.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")'` instead of writing the url like url = "GetMedicine". It would generate the url to the action properly.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Thank you. I'll try that one.

Comment: did that solution work?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny No. It didn't.

Comment: Then, its not an issue with the link... Check the parameters. And their datatype.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny The parameter isExp is a bool. is it wrong?

Comment: There could be many problems without action we cant tell much

Comment: Bool as a parameter is not a problem but check weather the ajax is sending a Boolean. Put a debugger before ajax and check the value.

Comment: Move code to separate js file and debug using F12. And check is ajax call is made or not !

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. One error is the action that I use to trigger is not an action result. It is a list. I changed it. I also I have did some changes in js. It works properly now.

```
var GetMedicine= function () {
var url = UrlMedicine.GetMedicineChecked;

var isExp = $('#isExp').val();
        var url = url + '?isExp=' + isExp;
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Please Select Expird medicine</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#medicineId").html(markup).show();
            }

        });
}

var GetMedicineList = function () {
    if ($('#isExp').is(":checked")) {
        userMedicineHistory.GetMedicine();
    }
}
return {
    GetMedicineList: GetMedicineList,
    GetMedicine: GetMedicine
};
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#isExp").change(userMedicineHistory.GetMedicineList)
});
```